# sql server Select mapping query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have these tables:

Table `Tb1` (`ID Int, CodeID Int, Value Int`)

```
 ID     CodeID    Value
 ----------------------
 1      1         10
 2      1         14
 3      1         5
 4      1         25
 5      2         12
 6      2         17
 7      2         4
 8      2         10
 9      2         6
```

Table `Tb2` (`CodeID Int Value Int`)

```
CodeID    Value
---------------
1         25
2         20
```

I want a query for get records from Tb1 where

```
SUM(Tb1.Value) <= Tb2.Value
```

For example result for above records is :

```
Tb1.ID   Tb1.CodeID  Tb1.Value   UsedValue     Tb2.Value
--------------------------------------------------------
1         1          10          10            25
2         1          14          14            25
3         1          5           1             25
5         2          12          12            20
6         2          17          8             20
```

I want a query without cursor.

`UsedValue` is `Tb1.Value` until sum of `Tb1.Value` was lowest than `Tb2.Value`.

I asked this question before : [Select SQL Mapping Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14422864/select-sql-mapping-query)

following query is a query without cursor but my data is very large and below query is slow.

```
;WITH Subtotals
AS
(
  SELECT
    T1.Id, T1.CodeId, SUM(T2.Value) SubTotal  
  FROM Tb1 T1
    JOIN Tb1 T2
       ON T1.CodeId = T2.CodeId
         AND T1.Id >= T2.Id
  GROUP BY T1.Id, T1.CodeId
)
SELECT
    S.ID,
    S.CodeID,
    T1.Value,
    CASE WHEN T2.value >= S.Subtotal
         THEN T1.value
         ELSE T1.value - (S.Subtotal - T2.value)
    END UsedValue,
    T2.Value T2Value
FROM Subtotals S
   JOIN Tb2 T2
      ON S.CodeId = T2.CodeId
   JOIN Tb1 T1
      ON S.Id = T1.Id
WHERE T2.Value >= S.SubTotal - T1.Value
```

I look for a query with above performance.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should do the job. Tested the performance compared to yours and with the values set here it uses up half as much time as your sample query. With twice more data it uses 1/3:rd of the time it takes to run your sample query. So it is definitely more efficient, but how much depends on the overall data in your tables, which you need to test out. [(Get the fiddle example here)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5b40/1/0):

```
SELECT T1.*
    , CASE WHEN CA.SumValue < T2.Value THEN T1.Value
        ELSE (T1.Value+T2.Value) - CA.SumValue
        END AS UsedValue
    , T2.*
FROM Tb1 T1
JOIN Tb2 T2 ON T2.CodeID = T1.CodeID
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(C1.Value) SumValue 
    FROM Tb1 C1 WHERE C1.CodeID = T1.CodeID AND C1.ID <= T1.ID) CA
WHERE ((T1.Value+T2.Value) - CA.SumValue) > 0
-- Probably a better way to do this, but the beef is above.
AND T1.CodeID IN 
    (SELECT T2.CodeID 
    FROM Tb2 T2
    JOIN (SELECT CodeID, SUM(VALUE) SumVal 
        FROM Tb1
        GROUP BY CodeID) SRC
    ON SRC.CodeID = T2.CodeID AND SRC.SumVal > T2.Value)
```

The section after the comment is what I'm dubious about, it's what makes sure only those records where the sum of Tb1 exceed the value of Tb2 are handled. Not the most performance-effective way to do that.

Otherwise the part above it should work fine. Also, if you want to display results where UsedValue is 0, since the previous row already reached the total sum = Tb2.Value, then just change the line below to **>= 0** instead.

```
WHERE ((T1.Value+T2.Value) - CA.SumValue) > 0
```

**EDIT**: Oh, and fiddle doesn't show all the columns belonging to the result. So ignore that, and try it out in SSMS to get the full result set.